# Need to remove padding on slider due to class= 'hidden-xs col-sm-3' in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

I am creating a slider in my page using bootstrap3 as following:

```css
/*Add css here*/
```

```html
<section id="slider">

                <ul class="rslides" id="modest-slider">

                    <li class="slider-wrapper hidden-xs col-sm-3">

                        <div class="slider-img-container"><img src="assets/images/slider1.png" alt="slider1" /></div>
                        <div class="slider-caption container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="slider-caption container">
                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4 );">
                                        <h1_2>Exclusively New Concept!</h1_2>
                                        <p class="slider-description2">
                                            Inspired by Scandinavian Design and made with all the richness from India, we present an exclusive range of home furnishing products ...
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.slider-caption -->

                    </li>
                    <!-- /.slider-wrapper -->
    </ul>
    </section>
```

I am using `hidden-xs col-sm-3` `class` for hiding the slider on resizing,
But when I use this class my banner get padding in left and right: Please refer the screen shots:

Slider with  hidden-xs col-sm-3

[image: Image with class hidden-xs col-sm-3]

I have marked with redline you can see the padding.

What I need is as follows (Here I am using it without class `hidden-xs col-sm-3`)

[image]

How can I make I remove the padding which coming due to the addition of `hidden-xs col-sm-3`? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share fiddle demo?

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe https://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/5noxhp88/ . Please enlarge your  HTML fiddle section to see result!!

Comment: it is the `col-sm-3` class which gives you padding, just remove it. use a descendant selector or add a new class to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem right, Try this:

```
#modest-slider li.col-sm-3 {
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: #modest-slider li.col-sm-3 {
 padding-left: 0; padding: - right:0;
} Thank you buddy!!